# Perl Regex - Exclude a pattern

Tags: regex, perl, replace, find

for which I have to replace all numbers with a text tag 'NUMBER'. but there is a certain condition it shouldn't be changed, when ever a number exists with an underscore in it .. (e.g 123_456). I am using

```
s/\d+/NUMBER/g
```

but it changes the likes of 123_456 to NUMBER_NUMBER. Is there a way to exclude it? The [^xyz] pattern might not work, as it negates a single character at a time (this is my understanding). Any ideas ? Input file sample is: The last number shouldn't be changed.

```
received for code:3
received for code:1
received for code:9
received for code:33
received for code:4
received for code:323_456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundaries to avoid matching digits that are followed by a underscore:

```
s/\b\d+\b/NUMBER/g
```

Comment: Sorry but there are other fields which can have enteries like ... =4521 or :12. Would boundary work on them as well ? it might not only be preceding space always.

Comment: @user3195304 `\b` marks boundaries between 'words' in regex. 'word' characters include letters, digits, and underscores. As long as you don't have something like `foo123` that you want to match, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Match only groups of digits that don't have a _ before or after:

```
s/(?<![_0-9])[0-9]+(?![_0-9])/NUMBER/g;
```

Note that `\d` isn't usually what people want, since it can match many more characters that are characterized as digits than just 0-9.  (Though the /a flag does make it mean just 0-9.)